# Does panpsychism imply consciousness after death?

Tags: consciousness

Does panpsychism imply that after we die, we will still exist as some form of consciousness? It might be so faint that we are barely aware of anything, but it might still be consciousness. Is there any philosopher who has considered such a possibility?

Comment: I think different panpsychists would have different ideas about identity and continuity of consciousness over time even before death, and their answer would presumably depend on that. For example, take the experiences associated with my brain right now, and the experiences associated with my brain exactly a day ago--do they belong to the "same consciousness" in any more fundamental sense than the experiences associated with two different people's brain at a given moment? Not all panpsychists would say they do, and if they did they would need some model of how identity works.

Comment: No. [Panpsychism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/panpsychism/#DefiPanp) posits some sort of rudimentary experiencing even in inanimate objects that manifests as consciousness when they combine in special ways that are sufficiently complex. Once the combination disintegrates its individual consciousness falls apart and reverts back to that rudimentary experiencing. If you want individual consciousness surviving, even dimly, you need something more along the lines of Cartesian dualism.

Comment: Spinoza maintained that some aspect in the mind is eternal and does not cease to exist with the body's demise. Go to wikisource, "Ethics" Part 5, On Human Freedom. The notion has never satisfactorily been explained in the extant. But appears to revolve around the notion that our adequate ideas are a part of 'infinite intellect'. Accumulating a cohesive intuitional grasp of eternity in 'scientia intuitiva', affords access to a kind of a sense of belonging to eternity.  Doubt whether this is believable, but read it for yourself and decide. Academia.edu has papers on life after death. Good luck

Comment: @Conifold - I don't think you necessarily need Cartesian dualism to posit some kind of survival, for example there are absolute idealist versions of panpsychism like that of Timothy Sprigge who imagined the Absolute as "a single divine consciousness within which an inconceivably vast number of streams of finite experience interact and interweave", not sure if he ever commented on death but perhaps we are all "remembered" by the Absolute. And certain types of Buddhism like Yogacara have been interpreted in an idealist way, and Buddhism imagines rebirth as something that doesn't require a soul.

Comment: There are various forms of panpsychism. My view is monist. So survival of the identity is not indicated. I accept the possibility that identity might be preserved in some simulation or collective. That is a whole other story.

Comment: @Conifold Is the whole greater than the sum of its parts?

Answer (score 0):

This does not follow from panpsychism. Panpsychism proposes that consciousness exists at a fundamental level. You are referring to survival of the human mind or soul after death. This relies on mind-body dualism. Panpsychism is monist. In my view, its foundation is in Russellian Monism. The fundamental stuff of the universe is matter-consciousness. Either way, you are asking about the survival of identity, of self-consciousness. I think that it is useful to consider various levels of consciousness. Awareness, sentience, consciousness, self-consciousness. Non-living things, living things without a nervous system, living things with a nervous system, living things with a sense of identity. Quark, slime mould, fish, ape. Aside from religious explanations, we would need to consider survival of identity within some sort of simulation. That is a whole other story.